# PrimeNg : Export Org Chart as Image / PDF

Tags: angular, charts, export, primeng, orgchart

We are using PrimeNg Org chart and we need to send that chart as part of PDF report.

PrimeNg Org Chart : https://primefaces.org/primeng/organizationchart

How can we achieve this?

Tried the below approach but it's failing with the error "Property 'getBase64Image' does not exist on type 'OrganizationChart'"

```
<p-organizationChart #orgchart [value]="programStructure" styleClass="company" selectionMode="single" [(selection)]="selectedProgram" [preserveSpace]="false">
...
...
@ViewChild("orgchart") orgchart: OrganizationChart; 
...
export(chart) {
    this.chartImg = this.orgchart.getBase64Image();
}
```